# How to replace list values with NA?

Tags: r, list, na

having following list:

```
> mylist <- list(x=1:3, y=c(1,0.8,1))
```

how to replace `mylist$y!=1` with NA

Comment: `lapply(mylist, function(i)replace(i, i != 1, NA))` or just `mylist$y <- replace(mylist$y, mylist$y != 1, NA)` for only `y`

Comment: Or `is.na(mylist$y) <- mylist$y != 1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mylist$y[mylist$y!=1] <- NA

mylist

# $x
# [1] 1 2 3
# 
# $y
# [1]  1 NA  1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
with(mylist,modifyList(mylist,list(y=replace(y,y!=1,NA))))
$x
[1] 1 2 3

$y
[1]  1 NA  1
```

Comment: or maybe just `within(mylist,y <- replace(y,y!=1,NA))` ?